# Package Name Doesn't Seem to Update

Tags: android, upload

I'm trying to upload an app I just made onto the app store, but whenever I try to upload the apk it says I need to use another package name besides com.example. So I went and changed it all but whenever I then go to generate a signed apk file it still gives me this error. I changed it in the manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.kazdev.michael.titanfall2hq">
```

It shows the correct name on the left through drop downs and I got rid of any extra packages that are unused. The app still runs and works fine. Where is the reference to com.example that is triggering this error.

Comment: What applicationId inside app build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

The package name is determined by what is set in your build script, you have to change it there too.

Comment: Yup that was the issue. Found it right after I posted of course.